# Profiling instruction cache misses

Tags: c++, caching

I'd like to construct a histogram of the instruction-cache-penalty incurred for each non-inlined function `f()` in my code. So if I have a total of k non-inlined functions in my code, I want k separate histograms. I'm wondering if there are any known solutions for this.

A naive approach for any one particular function `f1()` would be to find all calls to `f1()` in the code, record a timestamp value immediately prior to the call, and also record a timestamp at the start of `f1()`, constructing a histogram of the differences. It'd require adding (n+1) new lines of code, where n is the number of times `f1()` is called.

I basically want a scalable version of this naive solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are far more precise solutions available depending on your OS and processor. If you are on linux, use `perf_events`. It provides a good interface to PMU events. You can use this to get exact counts of icache-misses and sample the stack-snapshots on those events to figure out where the icache-misses are happening.

Comment: I have used perf, but as far as I know it only reports a single icache-miss count value. To attribute a delta in that count to a particular function seems non-trivial.

Comment: Try `perf record -e <your event name> --call-graph dwarf`, if you are using a new enough kernel. If not, you need to use `--call-graph fp` and build your applications without omitting the frame pointer. If you are using gcc, for example, the compiler option would be `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it yet, but will report back when I do. It looks promising